# XPath 1.0 to get highest date from XML

Tags: xpath

In an XML file I have a number of date fields. I need to find out which one is the highest value. Unfortunately, I have to use XPath 1.0, so there's not an easy way to do it.

I started out with this XML:

```
<root>
    <value>20120103</value>
    <value>20130103</value>
    <value>20120101</value>
    <value>20140103</value>
    <value>20100103</value>
</root>
```

From this, I can get the highest value with this xpath statement:

```
/root/value[not(text() <= preceding-sibling::value/text()) and not(text() <=following-sibling::value/text
())]
```

However, the real XML I'm working with got date fields like this:

```
<root>
    <value>2012-01-03</value>
    <value>2013-01-03</value>
    <value>2012-01-01</value>
    <value>2014-01-03</value>
    <value>2010-01-03</value>
</root>
```

To execute the same XPath, I have to use substring and concat to remove the minus signs. However, the application I'm using the XPath in and the Oxygen XML editor tell me that concat and substring are no Xpath 1.0 functions (although several pages tell me that they are...)

When I tell Oxygen that it's Xpath 2.0, I can get the values with this statement:

```
/root/value[not(concat(concat(substring(text(),1,4),substring(text(),6,2)),substring(text(),9,2)) <= preceding-sibling::value/concat(concat(substring(text(),1,4),substring(text(),6,2)),substring(text(),9,2))) and not
(concat(concat(substring(text(),1,4),substring(text(),6,2)),substring(text(),9,2)) <=following-sibling::value/concat(concat(substring(text(),1,4),substring(text(),6,2)),substring(text(),9,2)))]
```

Any ideas why it isn't working with Xpath 1.0 and how I can get around this?

Edit:

I thought I was getting closer by using translate to remove the minus signs:

```
/root/value[not(translate(text(),'-','') <= translate(preceding-sibling::value/text(),'-','')) and not(translate(text(),'-','') <=translate(following-sibling::value/text(),'-','')
)]
```

but for one or another reasons this produces two values:

2013-01-03
2014-01-03

While I would only expect the second one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This cannot be determined with a single XPath 1.0 expression because**:

1. In XPath 1.0 there isn't an `<` or `>` operator for strings.
2. Although one can use `translate()` to remove the hyphens from the context node, it isn't possible in a single XPath 1.0 expression to compare this with all other values, each of which has undergone the same translation.

**XPath 2.0 solution**:

```
max(/*/*/xs:date(.))
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe you're right, tried a lot of different solutions I found on the web, but none worked with Xpath 1.0. Guess I have to ask the software supplier for a version that implements Xpath 2

Comment: @ErikL, You are welcome. You can implement your own extension function, or better, start using XPath 2.0.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, your first XPath

```
/root/value[not(text() <= preceding-sibling::value/text()) and not(text() <=following-sibling::value/text())]
```

should work fine in both cases.

As long as the format is in year, month, day order with leading zeros...

However, it will not work, if there are duplicated days, so better use:

```
(/root/value[not(text() < preceding-sibling::value/text()) and not(text() < following-sibling::value/text())])[1]
```

Comment: well, it does in Xpath 2, but with Xpath 1 I just get 5 results (all dates)

Comment: Beni, In XPath 1.0 there is no `>` or `<` comparisson on strings -- therefore what you are saying in this answer isn't true.